# C# flag in use sql data

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms, visual-studio

We have a sql database where multiple users will be updating the customer records using physical printed forms which are scanned.

We will be getting 2000 forms in a day which will be done by 8-10 users.

Now whenever user wants to edit he should get a sql record which is not in process by some other user.

My question is if I flag the sql record when a user's starts the edit what should I do if the user stops a record in half.

How often should I check for incomplete records. What should be the best approach?

Comment: What do you mean by stops a record in half?

Comment: SQL server has no such locking facilities, you need to build them into your own application. For example, you could create a `RecordInUse` table, store IDs of records being edited in that table, and consult the table before starting an edit operation.

Comment: This sounds like a business requirement you should take up with the lead or the affected team on what they want to happen to the record. As to the how often, again up to the business how often they want the data freed

Comment: @PrestonM there are five six fields which needs to be check. What is user disconnect after checking 2 or 3

Answer (score 0):

what about if

1. you have a flag to mark the record as in-use
2. also you will add another date time column to show when the record is marked as "in-use"
3. you will a configurable expiration time (e.g.: 15 minutes) to unlock this record if the user didn't finish editing this record within this time.
   4- when another user try to edit this record you will check if the "in-use" flag is raised, and you will check if it exceeded the expiration interval

Comment: I was thinking on similar lines that is to add timestamp. Confusion is I will load the top 1 record order by account number, so I should check also check the timing at that time and enable also I should disconnect the other user if he wants to continue after 15 minutes.

Comment: you can make keep it up for the user so, when user try to pull up the data of certain record for editing you can ask him/her how long in minutes he needs to finish working on this record and this will be the expiration interval